# How to apply the labels of a variable in another in R (SAS FORMAT equivalent)

Tags: r, sas, format, label

Does anyone know how I can create a format of a variable in R and apply it to any other variable I want?

More specifically, I am trying to translate a SAS script to R script.

In SAS I can create a format of a variable like this:

```
PROC FORMAT

VALUE bool
1 = "Yes"
2 = "No"
3 = "NA"
;
```

(so the variable `bool` has the levels 1, 2, 3, where 1 will be replaced with "Yes", 2 with "No", etc)

Then I can indicate that for a specific variable of my data set (`myVariable`) - which also has the levels 1, 2, 3 - I want to have the same format:

```
FORMAT myVariable bool.;
```

so all the 1s will become "Yes", etc. Obviously, the order of the levels is not the same between the two variables, i just want to apply the same labels.

I cannot find how to do this with R, has anyone already done it?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind -- `proc format` is nothing but a behind-the-scenes `left join` on the values in a dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also create a function if you want to reuse the format (and not deal with factors if that is a problem).

```
library(dplyr)   
 lvl <- function(y){ifelse(y == 1, "Yes",
                              ifelse(y == 2, "No","NA"))}


df <- data.frame(
  answers = c(1,2,3)
)

df2 <- df %>% mutate(var2 = lvl(answers))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a look-up vector. For example.

```
v <-setNames(c("yes", "no","na"), 1:3))
v[c(1,2,2,3,1,1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla R, you can do this:

```
# create data
df <- data.frame(
  'answers' = c('1','2','3')
)

# make 'answers' into a factor
df$answers <- as.factor(df$answers)

#rename factor levels
levels(df$answers)
[1] "1" "2" "3"

levels(df$answers) <- c('Yes','No','NA')
```

In Tidyverse, this is slightly less clunky.

```
# you can also do this within tidyverse
library(tidyverse)

# create data
df <- data.frame(
  'answers' = c('1','2','3')
)

df %>% mutate(answers = as.factor(answers)) %>% 
recode(answers, '1' = 'Yes', '2'='No', '3'='NA')) -> df
```